# ElasticSearch: Boost only if multiple criteria are met

Tags: elasticsearch, nosql

I have the following ElasticSearch query:

```
    query: {
      bool: {
        must: [
          { match_all: {} }
        ],
        should: [
          { term: { company: { value: 'company', boost: 2 } } }
          { terms: { 'departments.id': 'company' } }
        ]
      }
    },
    sort: [
      '_score',
      { price: { order: 'desc' } }
    ]
  }
```

I want to boost if company term query matches, but I want to give an even bigger boost if and only if both the term query matches (company and department.ids).

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can write custom scoring logic, check [this out](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html). It is possible to write custom script and calculate desited score. You should see `script_score` section.